# A simple notation problem (bra ket notation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, notation, quantum-computer

[image]

How can it change this to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to know is how to do [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition),
in your case for example:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

The second thing to know is the convention for [ket vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Bras_and_kets_as_row_and_column_vectors):
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = |0\rangle  \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = |1\rangle $$

Comment: thank you very much